# Top value for generated picturebox isn't correctly adding

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code:

```vb
For Each srvr In discord.Guilds

  Dim top As Integer = 30
  Dim pb As New PictureBox
  pb.Width = 70
  pb.Height = 70
  pb.Left = 10

  pb.Top = top
  top = +30
  pb.Cursor = Cursors.Hand

  Dim ttImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(srvr.IconUrl)))
  pb.BackgroundImage = ttImage
  pb.Tag = srvr.Id.ToString + " | " + srvr.Name
  pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
  Me.Controls.Add(pb)
  pb.BringToFront()

Next
```

The problem is, I have no clue why the top value doesn't place the Pictureboxes lower. I've tried doing `top += 30` as well, not working at all. How can I make this work?

Comment: `top = +30` is a typo for `top += 30`

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, that's cleared and I know which to use now. As I stated in the post above I've done both and checked and I get the same problem as I described.

Comment: ...and maybe move `Dim top As Integer = 30` outside the loop. Or, better use a FlowLayoutPanel to layout the Controls. Possibly, download the Image once (since it appears it's always the same.).

Comment: @Jimi I've also tried it outside of the loop, same result. About the FlowLayoutPanel, I have no idea how that works.

Comment: @Jimi I've added the control to a FlowLayoutPanel and set the flow direction to TopDown, I've tried with and without the location settings, Same result and nothings changed. They're still stacking on top of each other

Comment: You cannot stack controls in FlowLayoutPanel. It's a *Flow* panel for a reason. You don't need to set the Location, just the Size. Then `myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(myNewPictureBox)`. Of course you have to give the FLP  a size that allows it to layout your controls.

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks. My issue was that one of the serverIcons from discord was set at default, which is an image of the letter of the guild. This was a problem because apparently it isn't an image so it was stopping there. I set the image and now it loads all of them into the panel as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is using a FlowLayoutPanel.
Create the panel on your form, and size it to the area you want to show the icons. Then, when you want to add a picturebox to it, do this:

```
  Dim pb As New PictureBox
  pb.Width = 70
  pb.Height = 70
  Dim ttImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New 
  MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(srvr.IconUrl)))
  pb.BackgroundImage = ttImage
  pb.Tag = srvr.Id.ToString + " | " + srvr.Name
  pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom

  FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb)
```

Notice how you don't need to specify the location. This is because the FlowLayoutPanel automatically calculates where the control should be placed.

If, however, you want to stick to your current method, the issue I noticed is that the Top variable is being declared within the for loop. This means every loop it makes, the old variable goes out of scope, and a new one is declared. So in short, since the variable is declared inside the for loop, nothing you do to it will pass over outside the loop, or in the next iteration of the loop, since it's a different variable.

Also, the correct syntax is

```
Top += 30
```

This should fix your issue:

```
    Dim TopSpacer As Integer = 30
    For Each serval In Discord.Guilds
        Dim PBico As New PictureBox With {.Size = New Size(70, 70),
            .Location = New Point(10, TopSpacer)}
        Dim WebClient As New WebClient
        Dim ImageBytes() As Byte = WebClient.DownloadData(serval.IconUrl)
        Dim IMG As Image = Image.FromStream(New IO.MemoryStream(ImageBytes))
        PBico.Image = IMG
        Me.Controls.Add(PBico)
        TopSpacer = TopSpacer + 100
    Next
```

In the code above, the 'Top' variable will be the same variable for each of the loops, because it is not within the loop's inner scope.

Comment: I've tried the second example, and used everything correctly. "Top" is not getting 30 added onto it. I've also tried the FlowLayoutPanel method they still stack on top of each other.

Edit: it was a discord.net issue I've fixed it

Comment: I'll re-write the last example, to see if there's any difference.

Comment: I noticed another issue. You were only adding 30 points to the y location. But the picture box's height is larger than that, meaning it overlaps.